# How old is Blender?

Tags: versions

When was the first Blender version released? I have been an avid user of blender for a few years but I still have not found out how long it has been around. I not only would like to know when it was released but try to run it. If someone could provide a link that would be great.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Blender celebrates January 2, 1994 as its birth day**, based on the timestamps from the first backup of the codebase. It was first used in production around 1 year later, in Q2 1995.

Refs: [tweet from the Blender Foundation](https://twitter.com/blender_org/status/1212678174703804416) and [from Ton Roosendal](https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/1212681372772577280).

---

During its first years, it wasn't free and open source. It became free thanks to a crowfounding campaign in 2002, when the first version was released to the public.

**The complete history is [on the History page of the Blender website](https://www.blender.org/foundation/history/).** There is also an interview made by Blender Guru to Ton Roosendaal, creator of Blender, **[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJEWOTZnFeg)**, that covers some of the history.

Judging by the [source repository on the website](https://download.blender.org/source/) the first ever open release is probably Blender 2.26, available [here](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.26/). In the [releases repository](https://download.blender.org/release/) you can find versions as old as Blender 1.0! I doubt you'll be able to use it though, it's just for [IRIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRIX).

[Edit Jan 2020] The code from the earliest backup (definitely not in a releasable state) has been made available too: [here](https://download.blender.org/source/chest/blender-jan-8-1994/).

---

If you can't get old versions to work, there is somebody on Youtube that in 2014 tried to go back in time, reporting on their experiments: [Blender 2.40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onRXLqENQhM), [Blender 2.27](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN9otMmC23M), [Blender 1.80](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huyiKyGi4do). Then they said  «*I probably do not want to continue to Blender 1.60, because in this version, I cannot save files.*»

Comment: They still work! [Here's proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB7In.png) (those two version because they are ones I had sitting around already).

Comment: I just realised that probably the first time I used blender (2003) it was around version 2.0x. After one year of poor experiments, I abandoned the hobby and didn't use it again until much later, probably 2.6x

Comment: I think if someone has a 32-bit machine they can run Blender 1.60. https://download.blender.org/release/Blender1.60/

Comment: There is something I have been wondering for a while about blender: How many times did the system requirements change and by how much?

Comment: @ToshibaSatellite this is a list you could compile yourself by looking at the Readme files in that folder. I don't think anybody has done such research. However, the definition of "system requirement" is rather fuzzy: some things may be partially supported on limited hardware. Also, some hardware/software combinations might have just never been officially tested.